# Simulation of lock screen android

Tags: android, lockscreen

i know it's dumb question but i am rely desperate here. Can you tell me where can i find Manifest file and resource folder for [these classes](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/mylockforandroid/Catalogmylockforandroid.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

There is an apk here: http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/downloads/list

you can download and unzip it, the manifest and res folder is in there.

Comment: I tried that already but when i unzip .apk file, and open manifest or res xml files i cant't read them for some reason.

Comment: What do you see when you open them? What do you use to open them?